# Populate array of integers from a comma-separated string of numbers and hyphenated number ranges

Tags: php, arrays, integer, range, text-parsing

I want to translate/hydrate/expand/parse a comma-separated string of integers and hyhenated integer range expressions and populate an array with its equivalent values as individual integers elements.

Input strings might look like the following:

```
3,5,6,9,11,23
```

or

```
3-20
```

or

```
3-6,8,12,14-20
```

I want to return these as an array of integers, so the last one would become:

```
[3,4,5,6,8,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Is there either a function available that does this, or how would I start in writing one?

Comment: The reverse procedure can be found here: [Shortening list of numbers with hyphens between consecutive numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9448129/367456).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`range`](http://php.net/range) function and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$input = '3,5,6,9,11,23,14-77';

$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', function($m) {
    return implode(',', range($m[1], $m[2]));
}, $input);
```

gives you:

```
3,5,6,9,11,23,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/84207)

How it works: You basically have two tokens in your string: the range-token `(1-n)` (defined as [*regular expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html): `(\d+)-(\d+)`) and the fallback (anything else).

[`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) allows the expansion of the token string by a callback function. That callback function then just expands the two matched numerical values into the comma-separated list by using PHP's [`range`](http://php.net/range) function and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode).

After that the string is in a normalized format you can just [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) it:

```
// as array:

print_r(explode(',', $result));
```

[Full Demo](https://eval.in/84208)

---

And after years as it was requested well formulated, the integer array, you can easily treat it as a [JSON Array](https://php.net/json_decode):

```
$result = json_decode('['. preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', function($m) {
    return implode(',', range($m[1], $m[2]));
}, $input) .']');
var_dump($result);
```

[Demo PHP 5.3-8.1](https://3v4l.org/dMlFp) + [Git Master](https://3v4l.org/dMlFp/rfc#vgit.master)

Comment: @mickmackusa: Yes, the square brackets were missing, and then PHP handles this well as integers, see the update.

Comment: @AlixAxel: [`addcslahes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) does in the format `\0..\377` which is octal -- not decimal -- so `\1..\11` for `1..9` and is perhaps not what you've been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a formalization/formulation of [hakre's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698869/1431728):

```
function rangesToList($a, $max) {
    $a = trim($a);
    if (isset($max) && substr($a, -1) == "-") {
        $a .= $max;
    }
    $r = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', function($m) {
        return implode(',', range($m[1], $m[2]));
    }, $a);
    return array_map('intval', explode(",", $r));
}
```

In addition to being encapsulated into a formula and a little more robust, it also takes an optional `$max` argument so that you can give it input like this:

```
$in = "2,4,6-8, 12-";
$out = rangesToList($in, 14);
```

and get this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 13
    [7] => 14
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function list2array ($list) {
    $array = explode(',', $list);
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $explode2 = explode('-', $value);
        if (count($explode2) > 1) {
            $range = range($explode2[0], $explode2[1]); 
            $return = array_merge($return, $range);
        } else {
            $return[] = (int) $value;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Result:

```
php > print_r(list2array('3-6,8,12,14-50'));
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 14
    [7] => 15
    [...]
    [41] => 49
    [42] => 50
)
```

It doesn't have error reporting by the way, you can put that in there by yourself :).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the potential attraction to my snippet will be its brevity.  After exploding the input string on commas, it unconditionally generates a range of one or more integers and pushes them into the result array.  When there is no hyphenated range expression, the lone number is passed to `range()` as the first and second parameter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/e7GOm))

```
$result = [];
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $v) {
    $x = explode('-', $v);
    array_push($result, ...range($x[0], $x[1] ?? $v));
}
var_export($result);
```

---

It may be more performant to use a condition to avoid excess function calls.  `sscanf()` will parse the string, convert numbers to integers, and return the number of assignments that it made.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cvgO2))

```
$result = [];
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $v) {
    if (sscanf($v, '%d-%d', $start, $end) === 1) {
        $result[] = $start;
    } else {
        array_push($result, ...range($start, $end));
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

To tweak @hakre's snippet to return int type values, you can wrap the modified string in square braces and call `json_decode()`. Because the numeric values are not quote-wrapped, json_decode will return int typed values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/781m0))

```
var_export(
    json_decode(
        '['
        . preg_replace_callback(
              '/(\d+)-(\d+)/',
              fn($m) => implode(',', range($m[1], $m[2])),
              $string
          )
        . ']'
    )
);
```

Comment: that's funny, I came to the same conclusion (`json_decode`). It's likely that the decoding is faster then applying `intval()`, haven't dipped into `sscanf`, it has some `*` functionality, but didn't tried it.

Comment: Yeah, [I'm aware of the assignment suppression functionality](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6927900694716768256?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop), but I don't see it being much use here.

Comment: Yes, I have not tried and only saw your answer here after editing in json_decode in mine. `sscanf` is pretty standard thought and way older than JSON Text _and_ has %d as well, therefore it might be some spot for typing string values in PHP itself, too. I'm using it from time to time btw., for example to differentiate between digits, hexits and strings (of any kind within ASCII). No idea if JSON actually parses Unicode number characters as integers (like the one [1] in a circle etc., e.g. 4 in a circle and 2 in a circle as int 42). JSON.org and the RFCs are short on that. /E: lnk d.n.wrk.4me

Answer (score 0):

I don't any function. You could explode the string by "," and then check if it is a range expression and insert the values.

Example code (don't know how the array should look like & doesn't support negative values but could be easily added):

```
$input = "3-6,8,12";
$output = array();


$strings = explode(",", $input);
foreach( $strings as $value ) {
    if( stripos( $value, "-") === false ) {
        $output[(int) $value] = (int) $value;
    } else {
        $range = explode("-", $value);

        $range[0] = (int) $range[0];
        $range[1] = (int) $range[1];

        if( $range[0] <= $range[0] ) {
            for ($i = $range[0]; $i <= $range[1]; $i++) {
                $output[$i] = $i;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump( $output );
```

This produces output:

```
array(6) { [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(5) [6]=> int(6) [8]=> int(8) [12]=> int(12) }
```

Comment: Or, you could use `range()` to push and save up some lines of code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $input="1,2,5-9,12,19";
    $iarr=explode(",", $input);



    $oarr=array();

    $rex='/([0-9]{1,})\-([0-9]{1,})/';

    for($i=0; $i<count($iarr); $i++) {
        preg_match($rex, $iarr[$i], $arrs);
        if(!$arrs) {
            array_push($oarr, $iarr[$i]);
        } else {
            $oarr=array_merge($oarr, range($arrs[1], $arrs[2], 1));
            /* Save a few lines of code by removing this and using above. Same difference, though
            for($j=$arrs[1]; $j<=$arrs[2]; $j++) {
                array_push($oarr, $j);
            } */
        }
    }



    print_r($oarr);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 9
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 19 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '2,3,4,5-10';
$strArr = explode(',',$str);
$finalArr = array();
$m = array();
foreach($strArr as $v) {
    $m = preg_split(":-:",$v);
    $start = $m[0];
    $finish = (isset($m[1]) ? $m[1] : $m[0]);
    $range = range($start,$finish);
    foreach($range as $r) $finalArr[] = $r;
}
print_r($finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more function:

```
function arrayFromList($list){
    $return = array();
    foreach(explode(',',$list) as $item){
        if(($dash = strpos($item, '-', 1)) !== FALSE){
            $return = array_merge($return, range(substr($item, 0, $dash),substr($item,$dash+1)));
        }
        else{
            $return[] = (int)$item;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

This one is aware of negative numbers if you need it, so input like `-4--1,1` will also work.