# Sort months so they are in a continuing sequence

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of months (numbers, 1-12) which I want to sort in a was that will make the largest continuing sequence. An example:

`array(1,2,3)`:

is simple, that's Jan-Mar, no sorting needed

`array(1,2,11,12)`:

This could be one continuing sequence November-February, so it should be sorted like 11,12,1,2

`array(1,4,5,11,12)`:

This should be Apr-May, November-Jan, so it should be split in two: 4,5 and 11,12,1

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I tried something with usort but get stuck pretty soon. It might be a Friday afternoon block though....

Comment: unfortunately, `usort` won't do the job as this is not a task of comparing two elements each time. You have to keep some context.

Comment: Is result of `yoursort(array(1,4,5,11,12))`  `array(4,5,11,12,1)` or `array(11,12,1,4,5)` ?

Comment: Easy to understand code vs efficiency of execution, which would you prioritise for this?

Comment: @madfriend Best thing would be array(array(4,5),array(11,12,1))

Comment: @Ryven efficiency of execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look on your data, we see the following preconditions:

1. The maximum range is from 1 to 12.
2. The input is sorted and therefore ordered.
3. There is only one place where the wrap-around happens: from 12 to 1.

Taking this into account, we can say the following:

1. The first value is 1 or there is no wrap around.
2. And the last value is 12 or there is no wrap around.
3. If there is a wrap around, all consecutive months from the beginning (1,2,...) are wrapped around.

That is a relatively simple function:

```
function group_months(array $months) {
    $count = count($months);
    if (!$count || $months[0] != 1 || $months[$count-1] != 12 || $count === 12) {
        return $months;
    }
    for ($size = 1; $months[$size] === $size+1;) {
        $size++;
    }
    return array_merge(array_slice($months, $size), range(1, $size));
}
```

Or in a shift-push variant (move 1,2,... to end):

```
function group_months(array $months)
{
    $count = count($months);
    if ($count && $count != 12 && $months[$count - 1] === 12) {
        for ($month = 1; $months[0] === $month; $month++) {
            $months[] = array_shift($months);
        }
    }
    return $months;
}
```

Or in a pop-unshift variant (Move ..,11,12 to front):

```
function group_months(array $months)
{
    $count = count($months);
    if ($count-- && $count != 11 && $months[0] === 1) {
        for ($month = 12; $months[$count] === $month; $month--) {
            array_unshift($months, array_pop($months));
        }
    }
    return $months;
}
```

If you then want to group the numbers in the array, please see a related question that has a solution for string output already:

- [Shortening list of numbers with hyphens between consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9448129/367456)

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do once you figure out how to express the fact that `12` can wrap around to `1`.

Here is my solution. It naturally sorts the incoming array, then creates a `$months` array that looks like this:

```
$months = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

From that array, I loop over the input array to place zeros where a month value isn't set.
So, with an input array of `array( 1, 2, 11, 12)`, the `$inputs` array becomes:

```
$inputs = 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  11 12 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  11 12
```

From here, the algorithm is simple: Loop over the `$inputs` array to find the longest sequence that isn't 0. This will generate all of the possible sequential sequences.

```
function sort_months( $array)
{
    natsort( $array);

    $keys = array_flip( $array);
    $inputs = array();
    $months = array_merge( range( 1, 12), range( 1, 12));

    foreach( $months as $m) {
        $inputs[] = (isset( $keys[$m])) ? $m : 0;
    }

    $sequences = array();

    for( $i = 0, $ii = count( $inputs); $i < $ii; $i++) {
        if( $inputs[$i] != 0) {
            $sequence = array( $inputs[$i]);
            for( $k = $i + 1, $kk = $ii + 1; $k < $kk;  $sequence[] = $inputs[$k], $k++) {
                if( !isset( $inputs[$k]) || $inputs[$k] == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            $sequences[] = $sequence;
        }
    }

    return $sequences;
}
```

With the input `array( 12, 11, 1, 2)`, this [will output](http://viper-7.com/ovmC4M):

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    int(12)
    [2]=>
    int(1)
    [3]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(12)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(12)
  }
}
```

You can see that the longest sequential sequence is in fact present in the array (along with every other possible sequence):

```
[2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    int(12)
    [2]=>
    int(1)
    [3]=>
    int(2)
  }
```

I am leaving it up to the OP to determine how to pick which sequences to use that represent all of the months that were inputted to the function.

Comment: Nice solution. I picked the one from Jocelyn as the answer since it gives the right array back and in yours there has to be an additional filter.

Comment: @Nin - Functionality isn't everything - Compare efficiencies and you'll notice a huge difference.

Comment: Could you please explain why yours is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

My PHP isn't good enough to write an implementation, but I'd be curious to see if this is possible by using a circular array, or a Linked List structure.

First, create such a structure with 12 boolean elements, making it circular by having the `next` property of the final element set to the first element. Conversely, the `previous` element of the first is set to the final element. This represents your 'wrap-around' calendar.

You can then read in your array, setting each element of your 'calendar' to `true` where the element index appears in the input array.

You then loop around your 'calendar' until you find the largest unbroken sequence of `true` elements. Repeat to find any smaller ones and output these as arrays.

Hopefully that's a feasible starting point for you and I'd be interested to see someone realise it in PHP!

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration, I worked it out simplified only with the order that is in the array already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11595641/367456

Answer (score 1):

Try the PHP function below. It works fine with all 3 examples given:

```
<pre>
<?php
function split_months($array)
{
    // remove duplicate values, if any
    // sort the array in ascending order
    $array = array_unique($array);
    sort($array);

    $results = array();

    // loop until the array is empty
    while(!empty($array))
    {
        // extract the first entry of the array
        $entry = array_shift($array);

        if(empty($results))
            $results[] = array($entry);
        else
        {
            // find in which sub-array of $results $entry needs to be stored
            foreach($results as $index => $values)
            {
                // extract the last value
                $last = array_pop($values);

                // compare with $entry
                if($entry-1 == $last)
                {
                    $results[$index][] = $entry;
                    unset($entry);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // there was no sub-array to store $entry: store it in a new sub-array
            if(isset($entry))
            $results[] = array($entry);
        }
    }

    // if $results contain no array, or only one, there is nothing to optimize
    if(sizeof($results) <= 1)
        return $results;

    // lastly, search if one result sub-array is starting with "1", and another is ending with "12"
    // in that case, join these 2 sub-arrays in one
    foreach($results as $index => $values)
    {
        if($values[0] == 1)
            $index1 = $index;
        elseif($values[sizeof($values)-1] == 12)
            $index12 = $index;

        if(isset($index1) && isset($index12))
            break;
    }
    if(isset($index1) && isset($index12))
    {
            // merge both sub-arrays
        $results[$index12] = array_merge($results[$index12], $results[$index1]);
            // remove the sub-array starting with "1"
        unset($results[$index1]);
    }

    return $results;
}

$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(1,2,11,12);
$array3 = array(1,4,5,11,12);

print_r(split_months($array1));
print_r(split_months($array2));
print_r(split_months($array3));
?>
</pre>
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are doing the things right. I mean example like your third one. `array(1, 2, 4, 5, 11, 12)` How can you be sure that these are not 3 sequences Jan-Feb, Apr-May and Nov-Dec or 2 sequences Nov-Feb and Apr-May. Is there any user input that controls this sequences or somethign else i shappening?

Comment: he means growing sequences that have a diff of 1 between elements.