# How to group numbers in ranges using PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

Let's say that I have the following sequence of numbers in an array:

```
$numbers = array(1,3,2,23,24,25,26, 8)
```

How can I print them in ranges, for instance:

> The numbers are 1-3, 23-26, 8.

Comment: The logic of grouping isn't clear. Why `1-3` and not `1-26`?

Comment: He wants to group sequences where all numbers are present

Comment: to build on @zerkms 's good point, what range do you consider to be 'out of range' is 5 numbers away too far? or only consecutive numbers??

Comment: Is the position of the 8 significant?  That is, would you also accept 1-3, 8, 23-26 as an answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sorry for not being more specific. I mean as @emartel says I need to group the numbers in sequence where all numbers are present.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a simple version, creating `groups` containing your ranges

```
<?php
$numbers = array(1,3,2,23,24,25,26,8);
sort($numbers);
$groups = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++)
{
    if($i > 0 && ($numbers[$i - 1] == $numbers[$i] - 1))
        array_push($groups[count($groups) - 1], $numbers[$i]);
    else // First value or no match, create a new group
        array_push($groups, array($numbers[$i])); 
}

foreach($groups as $group)
{
    if(count($group) == 1) // Single value
        echo $group[0] . "\n";
    else // Range of values, minimum in [0], maximum in [count($group) - 1]
        echo $group[0] . " - " . $group[count($group) - 1] . "\n";
}
```

The output is

```
1 - 3
8
23 - 26
```

Now, if the order of your ranges is important, like you described in your question, you can still sort your groups... from what I can see, you want the ranges first followed by the single values?  This can be done by adding

```
function groupRanges($a, $b)
{
    if(count($a) == 1)
        if(count($b) == 1)
            return 0; // equal
        else
            return 1; // so $b is considered less than

    if(count($b) == 1)
        return -1; // so $a is considered less than

    return 0; // both are ranges, keep them there... could be adjusted to compare the size of each range
}

usort($groups, "groupRanges");
```

right before the `foreach` and the output becomes:

```
1 - 3
23 - 26
8
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, the part I was missing was sorting the array before grouping.

Comment: I just added a second part if you want range 1, range 2, single number... by modifying `groupRanges` you can control how your ranges will appear in the final array

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = array(1,3,2,23,24,25,26,8);

$result = array();

$sorted = $numbers;
sort($sorted);

$current = null;
foreach ($sorted as $v) {
    if (is_null($current)) {
        $current = array($v, $v);
    } else {
        if ($current[1] + 1 == $v) {
            $current[1] = $v;
        } else {
            $result[] = $current;
            $current = array($v, $v);
        }
    }
}

$result[] = $current;

$arranged = array();

foreach ($numbers as $v) {
    foreach ($result as $k => $r) {
        if ($v >= $r[0] && $v <= $r[1]) {
            $arranged[] = $r;
            unset($result[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($arranged);
```

http://ideone.com/i2YGod

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I had to do it.

```
<?php
$numbers = array(1,3,2,23,24,25,26,8);
sort($numbers);
$x=0;
$output = array();
foreach($numbers as $k=>$n){
    if(isset($numbers[$k+1]) && $numbers[$k+1]==$n+1){
        $output[$x][]=$n;
    }elseif(isset($output[$x][count($output[$x])-1]) && $output[$x][count($output[$x])-1]+1==$n){
        $output[$x][]=$n;
    }else{
        $x++;
        $output[$x][] = $n;
        $x++;
    }
}
foreach($output as $o){
    echo $o[0];
    if(isset($o[count($o)-1]) && $o[count($o)-1]!=$o[0]){
        echo ' - '.$o[count($o)-1];
    }
    echo '<br>';
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could not post this yesterday, so I'm very late. Thought it was elegant enough to share it.

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1, 3, 2, 23, 24, 25, 26, 8);
sort($numbers);
$result = array();

while (count($numbers) > 0)
{
    $begin = reset($numbers);
    $end = array_shift($numbers);

    while (in_array($end + 1, $numbers))
    {
        $end = array_shift($numbers);
    }
    $beginAndEnd = array_unique(array($begin, $end));
    $result[] = implode('-', $beginAndEnd);
}
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array, say array `A`. Then do a binary search on it. 
Say the array is of size `n`:

take `A[n/2]`, the element at `n/2`.

if `A[n/2]-A[n/4] = n/2-n/4`, then 
`A[n/2]` and `A[n/4]` are in the same group-- skip `A[3n/8]` and check `A[n/8]` to see 
whether `A[n/2]-A[n/8] = n/2-n/8`.

if `A[n/2]-A[n/4] != n/2-n/4`, then you've got two groups at hand-- one that has 
`A[n/2]` in and the other that has `A[n/4]` in. check `A[n/8]` to see whether it is in the same group as 
`A[n/4]`. Check `A[3/8]` to see whether it is in the same group as `A[n/2]`, if not, whether 
in group of `A[n/4]`.

You can also combine it with the sort algorithm but i don't think it's worth it. This is fast-- in logarithmic time and is modular.

Comment: By "logarithmic", you mean "O(N log N)", right?  The sort alone makes it at least that.

Comment: somewhere between "purely" logarithmic and linear-- O(log n) in best case when the entire array is the range, O(n) in the worst case when every cell is a range, say all even numbers. but yes, sort algorithm sets the upper bound. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sorted = $numbers; 
sort($sorted);
$sorted[] = null;  # add a null so the last iteration stores the final range
$ranges = array();
$end = null;
$start = null;

foreach ($sorted as $x) {
    if ($start === null) {
        # first iteration.  New range, but there's no previous one to mention
        $start = $x;
    }
    elseif ($x !== $end + 1) {
        # non-contiguous values == new range.
        # squirrel away the one we were just working on, and start fresh
        $ranges[] = ($start === $end) ? "$start" : "$start-$end";
        $start = $x;
    }
    $end = $x;
}

$ranges_str = implode(', ', $ranges);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_ranges($numbers) {
sort($numbers);
$ranges=array();
while(current($numbers)){
$start=current($numbers);
$next=next($numbers);
$current=$start;
while( ($next-$current)==1){
    $current=$next;
    $next=next($numbers);
}
$ranges[]=array('start'=>$start,'end'=>$current);
}

return $ranges;

}
```