# Dividing an Array of Dates Into Contiguous Blocks

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check for consecutive dates within a set and return as range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range)

I have an array of dates which is obtained from a mySQL query. I need to divide the array into multiple arrays so that the dates in each array are contiguous.

So, if I start with

```
$datearray = array("2013-05-05", "2013-05-06", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-08", "2013-06-19", "2013-06-20", "2013-06-21");
```

I need to be able to split that into

```
$firstdatearray = array("2013-05-05", "2013-05-06", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-08");
$seconddatearray = array("2013-06-29", "2013-06-30", "2013-07-01");
```

Finally I will be able to print

> 5 - 8 Mar, 29 Jun - 1 Jul

How can I do that? I haven't a clue where to start.

Comment: You have no clue where to start? I bet you have at least one idea what you could do.

Comment: So you should really try to do something and then ask the question when you run into specific implementation problems.

Comment: similar, adaptable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**THIS IS THE COMPLETE WORKING ANSWER.  (Enjoy!)**

You'll have to loop through each value in $datearray

```
<?php

$datearray = array("2013-05-05", "2013-05-06", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-08", "2013-06-19", "2013-06-20", "2013-06-21");
asort($datearray);
$resultArray = array();
$index = -1;
$last = 0;
$out = "";

foreach ($datearray as $date) {
    $ts = strtotime($date);
    if (false !== $ts) {
        $diff = $ts - $last;

        if ($diff > 86400) {
            $index = $index + 1;
            $resultArray[$index][] = $date;
        } elseif ($diff > 0) {
            $resultArray[$index][] = $date;
        } else {
            // Error! dates are not in order from small to large
        }
        $last = $ts;
    }
}

foreach ($resultArray as $a) {
    if (count($a) > 1) {
        $firstDate = $a[0];
        $firstDateBits = explode('-',$firstDate);
        $lastDate = $a[count($a)-1];
        $lastDateBits = explode('-',$lastDate);

        if ($firstDateBits[1] === $lastDateBits[1]) {
            $out .= intval($firstDateBits[2]) . '-' . intval($lastDateBits[2]) . ' ' . date("M",strtotime($firstDate)) . ', ';  
        } else {
            $out .= date("M d",strtotime($firstDate)) . '-' . date("M d",strtotime($lastDate)) . ', ';  
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
5-8 May, 19-21 Jun
```

Comment: Thanks mrbinky. That is looking promising. I'm working on developing it fully into my application now. I'll come back when I have more news.

Comment: That was pretty much the "complete working answer". Just a few little things and it flies:
I didn't notice the $out = "": line at first, so I re-invented that wheel myself.
date("M d" etc in the last $out .= line gave me back-to-front dates and always two-character. Changing to date("j M" etc solved that.
The list of dates ended with a comma, so I used rtrim to tidy that up.

Comment: Thanks to @mrbinky3000 for a really helpful solution. It was much less painful than I was expecting. Thanks also to everyone else who took the trouble to look at it. I'm sure there are other working solutions here, but this was the one that I ran with.

Comment: There was one other issue I found once I started to use the solution. It didn't accomodate a single date that was not contiguous on either side. I just had to add and extra bit to the if...else routine to take account of that. The code can be seen in operation on (for example) www.littlehotels.co.uk/spain/noves.php. Click on the Room Rates tab.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PHP 5.3 or greater.

You can make use of DateTime, DateInterval, and a little algorithmic work.

```
// create the same array but with DateTime objects to represent the dates
$dt_array = array_map(function ($e) { return new DateTime($e); }, $datearray);


$intervals = array();
$len_dt_array_m1 = count($dt_array) - 1;
if ($len_dt_array_m1 >= 0) {
    $current_interval = &$intervals[];
}

// now we traverse the array left to right.
// if the difference between the current date and the next is not +1 day, we assume a new interval has begun.
for ($i = 0; $i < $len_dt_array_m1; ++$i) {
    $current_dt = $dt_array[$i];
    $next_dt = $dt_array[$i+1];
    $diff = $current_dt->diff($next_dt);
    $current_interval[] = $current_dt->format('Y-m-d');
    if ($diff->days != 1 || $diff->invert != 0) {
        $current_interval = &$intervals[];
    }
}

// add last dt to the interval
if ($len_dt_array_m1 >= 0) {
    $current_interval[] = $dt_array[$len_dt_array_m1]->format('Y-m-d');
}

print_r($intervals);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant help you with acutal code, but you could do something like this:

- find start and endpoints of the ranges
- count steps in between (1 step = 1 day)
- use mktime (or DateTime or strftime) to calc the end date based on start date + step days)
- print out as you like.

Answer (score 0):

All dates you have are in the same year. You could convert each date into the number of the day in that year.

Then you would have an array of numbers. For that array you can just do like outlined here:

- [Shortening list of numbers with hyphens between consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9448129/367456)

Another way would be to calculate the next date based on the previous on and then compare it with the next date in the array. If both equal, extend the current time-span, if not, create a new time-span. Reduce the array to time-spans then:

```
$consecutiveDates = function ($result, $date) {

    if ($count = count($result)) {
        $next = clone $result[$count - 1][1];
        $next->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }

    $date = new DateTime($date);

    if (!$count || $date != $next) {
        $result[$count++] = [$date];
    }

    $result[$count - 1][1] = $date;

    return $result;
};

$reduced = array_reduce($datearray, $consecutiveDates, []);
```

This gives the following result (for your array):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2013-05-05 00:00:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                )

            [1] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2013-05-08 00:00:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2013-06-19 00:00:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                )

            [1] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2013-06-21 00:00:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                )

        )

)
```

These two entries now can be easily mapped into your style of output with a mapping function:

```
$consecutiveDatesString = function ($pair) {

    list($start, $end) = $pair;

    return $start == $end
        ? $start->format('j M')
        : $start->format($start->format('M') != $end->format('M') ? 'j M' : 'j')
            . $end->format(' - j M');
};

$consecutiveDatesStrings = array_map($consecutiveDatesString, $reduced);
```

Which then leads to a more compact result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5 - 8 May
    [1] => 19 - 21 Jun
)
```

And to finally print that comma-separated:

```
echo implode(', ', $consecutiveDatesStrings), "\n";
```

Which gives, guess what:

```
5 - 8 May, 19 - 21 Jun
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$datearray = array("2013-05-05", "2013-05-06", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-08", "2013-06-19", "2013-06-20", "2013-06-21");
$current_date_array_index = 0;
$dates = array();

for($i=0,$c=count($datearray);$i<$c;$i++){
    if(strtotime($dates[$current_date_array_index][count($dates[$current_date_array_index])-1]." +1 day") != strtotime($datearray[$i])){
        $current_date_array_index++;
    }
    $dates[$current_date_array_index][] = $datearray[$i];
}

foreach($dates as $date){
    if(count($date) == 1){
        $output[] = date('j M',strtotime($date[0]));
    }else{
        $output[] = date('j',strtotime($date[0]))." - ".date('j M',strtotime($date[count($date)-1]));
    }
}

echo implode($output,", "); // output: 5 - 8 May, 19 - 21 Jun
```

It's worth noting that if the dates go over the month though, it'll say something like `29 - 5 Mar` - 29th of what is not defined so I would do `5 Mar - 8 Mar` if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$prev = null;
$groups = array();
$idx = 0;

foreach($datearray as $day)
{
    if ($prev == null)
    {
        $prev = $day;
    } else {
        $currentDay = strtotime($day);
        $prevDay =strtotime($prev);
        if ($currentDay + 86400 > $prevDay)
        {
        // New Array
        $idx++;
    }

    $groups[$idx][] = $day;

    }
}

// TODO : Sort the array into date order
```

Note: I have not tested the above code so it may contain typos.

I am simply iterating over each day in the array, and determining if it is a continuous day from the previous day.  If it is, then it's added to the same group, if it is not, then it is added to a different array index.  You may need to sort the dates after this using some sort of [sorting function from php](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).  Then iterate over the array groups to determine date range.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Date_Array_Split
{
    private $date_arrays = array();

    public function __construct( Array $dates, $split_into = 2 )
    {
        // Sort the array
        asort( $dates );

        // Calculate the array size to pass to array_chunk
        $size = ceil( count( $dates ) / $split_into );

        // Break up the array into pieces
        $dates = array_chunk( $dates, $size );

        $this->date_arrays = $dates;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $string = array();  // Oh, the irony!

        // Iterate through the chunks
        foreach( $this->date_arrays as $date_array )
        {
            // Here's the oldest date in the chunk
            $date_min = min( $date_array );

            // Here's the newest date in the chunk
            $date_max = max( $date_array );

            // Default format for output
            $date_min_format = 'j M';

            // Accomodate the slight formatting change
            if( date( 'my', strtotime( $date_min ) ) === date( 'my', strtotime( $date_max ) ) )
            {
                // Moth and year are the same, omit the month
                $date_min_format = 'j';
            }

            // String-i-fy the dates for output
            $date_min_string = date( $date_min_format, strtotime( $date_min ) );
            $date_max_string = date( 'j M', strtotime( $date_max ) );

            // Add them to the output array
            $string[] = sprintf( '%s - %s', $date_min_string, $date_max_string );
        }

        // Return the output array separated by commas
        return implode( $string, ", " );
    }
}

$dates_array = array(
    "2013-05-05", 
    "2013-06-20", 
    "2013-05-07", 
    "2013-05-08", 
    "2014-05-09", 
    "2013-05-09", 
    "2013-06-19", 
    "2013-06-21"
);

$dates = new Date_Array_Split( $dates_array );

echo( $dates );
```

Output: `5 - 9 May, 19 Jun - 9 May`

Note this is handling the years correctly.  That's why the output looks a bit odd.  Might want to account for that in the output.