# Needs Out Put Array according to description using PHP

Tags: php

I have this array as input:

```
 $input=array('01-08-2018','02-08-2018','03-08-2018','05-08-2018','06-08-2018','08-08-2018','10-08-2018','11-08-2018','14-08-2018','01-09-2018','02-09-2018','10-09-2018');
```

I need Expected Array: (Need separate array if sequential dates break.)

```
$output=array(
              array('01-08-2018','02-08-2018','03-08-2018'),
              array('05-08-2018','06-08-2018'),
              array('08-08-2018'),
              array('10-08-2018','11-08-2018'),
              array('14-08-2018'),
              array('01-09-2018','02-09-2018'),
              array('10-09-2018')
            )
```

> Note: It should work for dates like 31-8-2018,1-9-2018, It should come
>   in same array.

Comment: So the "pattern" is break after non sequential dates?

Comment: yes, exactly....

Comment: What do you have so far and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: What have you done so far to get it to work? Are you running into anything specific?

Comment: @jeroen I tried to develop script but not getting idea how to compare each one

Comment: You have a (`$output`) multidimensional array. So you need to use a foreach to loop through the arrays and check which condition meets an output. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: You should convert the entries to dates if you want to compare them. Check for example http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php on how to do that.

Comment: [this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201333/dividing-an-array-of-dates-into-contiguous-blocks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is exacly what you need

```
  function isSecuencial($date1, $date2) {
    // Compares if two dates are consecutive
    $day_diff = 86400; // Difference between two days
    return strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1) <= $day_diff;
  }

  $consecutiveIndex = 0;
  $output[$consecutiveIndex] = array($input[0]); 

  for ( $i=1; $i < sizeof($input); $i++) {
      if (isSecuencial($input[$i - 1], $input[$i])) {
          array_push($output[$consecutiveIndex], $input[$i]);
          continue;
      }
      $consecutiveIndex ++;
      $output[$consecutiveIndex] = array($input[$i]);
  }

  var_dump($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Closest thing I've got to it:

```
$input=array('31-07-2018','01-08-2018','02-08-2018','03-08-2018','05-08-2018','06-08-2018','08-08-2018','10-08-2018','11-08-2018','14-08-2018','31-08-2018', '01-09-2018','02-09-2018','10-09-2018');

$output = [];

$prevDay = 0;

$i=0;

foreach($input as $val)  {

    $dateExploded = explode("-", $val);

    if(date('t', strtotime(date($val))) == $dateExploded[0]) {

        $dateExploded[0] = 0;

    }

    if($dateExploded[0] != $prevDay + 1) {

        $i++;

    }

    $output[$i][] = $val;

    $prevDay = $dateExploded[0];



}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
[1] => Array (
    [0] => 31-07-2018
    [1] => 01-08-2018
    [2] => 02-08-2018
    [3] => 03-08-2018
    )
[2] => Array (
    [0] => 05-08-2018
    [1] => 06-08-2018
    )
[3] => Array (
    [0] => 08-08-2018
    )
[4] => Array (
    [0] => 10-08-2018
    [1] => 11-08-2018
    )
[5] => Array (
    [0] => 14-08-2018
    )
[6] => Array (
    [0] => 31-08-2018
    [1] => 01-09-2018
    [2] => 02-09-2018
    )
[7] => Array (
    [0] => 10-09-2018
)
```

Comment: `'31-05-2018','01-06-2018'` are sequential. However `31+1` is `32`, not `01`. Instead of working with the data as string consider then dates (which they are).

Comment: Totally right Ivanka, I was thinking the same. Also there are months that has 30 days, other 31 and february has 28, and what about leap years? The best approach is comparing the dates and in the case that the difference between two dates is higher than 24h just break the array and push the second date to a new index

Comment: It seems it works but it will not work for dates like  31-8-2018,1-9-2018, It should come in same array but using this it gives separate array